# "Couldn't find artefact" between two local projects (REST-API and GUI-project) (maven)

Tags: java, swing, api, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to link my two projects into one. One is a REST API meant to gather data and the other is a java swing app to create the GUI which is meant to controls the other. I've run both of them independently and they work fine. Though, when I add dependencies to each other and clean/build them. It returns the error message:

> "Failed to execute goal on project MainFrame: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.mycompany:MainFrame:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact com.mycompany:SoA_VII:jar:1.0 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]"

As far as I can tell my POM-file is declared correctly and I'm not sure where to look for solutions anymore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainFrame</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>       
       <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.48</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>SoA_VII</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoA_VII</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SoA_VII-1.0</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>MainFrame</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>```
````

Comment: Have you build the version 1.0 `MainFrame` and put it into your repository? I guess it is not available in maven central repository

Answer (score 0):

If you work locally then `clean install` both projects

Create/push to your own remote repository if you are sharing with a team